# Объединить два DF по условию

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Пусть дан первый DF:

```
YEAR    X1  X2
2010    1   7
2011    5   8
2012    4   8
2013    8   9
2014    56  6
2015    5   6
2016    6   5
2017    6   6
2018    5   5
2019    6   6
2020    6   6
```

И дан второй:

```
YEAR    X3
2010    1
2011    1
2012    1
2013    1
2012    2
2013    2
2014    2
2015    2
```

Нужно в первый DF добавить столбец X3, который подходит по годам, т.е. на выходе должны получить вот это:

```
YEAR    X1  X2  X3
2010    1   7   1
2011    5   8   1
2012    4   8   1
2013    8   9   1
2012    4   8   2
2013    8   9   2
2014    56  6   2
2015    5   6   2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом .merge():

```
res = df1.merge(df2)
```

Comment: Спасибо, я помню уже решали с помощью этой команды, но почему то подумал, что слишком просто в этой ситуации